# How to obtain the angle of rotation produced by a PCA on a 2D dataset?

Tags: r, pca

I want to find the principal direction in a set of spatial coordinates (i.e. in a 2D table). To do so I'm using PCA implemented in `prcomp` (because it allows missing values). `prcomp` returns a 'rotation' matrix which is said to be

> the matrix of variable loadings (i.e., a matrix whose columns contain the eigenvectors).

From this, I would like to calculate the angle of the rotation achieved by the PCA, expressed as the clockwise angle from the North direction. I know the information is there, but I cannot get the calculation right. Any help would be appreciated.

**EDIT:** It seems that `deg(asin(abs(rotation[1,1])))` works. My understanding of what I read elsewhere led me to that solution, but I don't feel like I would be able to correctly spell out an explanation for the benefit of others.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

In a 2D case, the `rotation` matrix is $2\times 2$ and contains two eigenvectors as its columns. The first eigenvector $(x,y)$ is given by the first column. Its angle to the horizontal axis (abscissa) is given by $$\alpha = \operatorname{arctan} (y/x).$$As all eigenvectors are scaled to have unit length, this is equal to $$\alpha = \operatorname{arccos} (x/1)=\operatorname{arccos} (x).$$
You might call it a "counterclockwise" angle "from the East direction". If you want a "clockwise" angle "from the North direction", then you need $$\beta = 90^\circ - \alpha=90^\circ - \operatorname{arccos} (x)=
\operatorname{arcsin} (x).$$
In R, it should be:

```
beta = asin(pc$rotation[1,1])*180/pi
```

which is more or less your formula too.

[image: PCA angles in 2D]

Comment: That's a simple and clear explanation for the records. Thanks.

Comment: Did you create that illustration yourself or did you find it somewhere? The handwritten/xkcd-like look is very appealing and I've been looking for ways to create simple graphs like that. It's clear, informative and looks very human (as opposed to more 'clinically clean' images). My math communication toolbox would greatly benefit from more figures like that .

Comment: @Beyer Thanks. I created this image myself, and I am happy to tell you how! I took a Post-It note, made a sketch with a pen, attached the note to an A4 piece of white paper, and scanned it :-) Then cropped and increased the contrast in a graphic editor. All in all, probably around five minutes.

Comment: Hahahaha I was afraid you'd say that. Thank you for taking the time. The post-it-to-scanner trick is now duly noted. Now I just need legible hand writing.

Comment: +1 for the sticky note attitude.